# Mongo aggregate – return zero count

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need your help in aggregate functions in Mongo.

I have such aggregation:

```
const likes = await this.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { post: postId },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$likeType',
      count: { $sum: 1 },
    },
  },
]);
```

It collects all likes/dislikes for a post and returns this:

```
[ { _id: 'pos', count: 40 }, { _id: 'neg', count: 3 } ]
```

I faced a problem: if there is only one type of likes (for example only 'pos'), it returns this:

```
[ { _id: 'pos', count: 40 } ]
```

But I need this array to show zero value too:

```
[ { _id: 'pos', count: 40 }, { _id: 'neg', count: 0 } ]
```

Is there any way to set default values for all types of _ids?

I understand that it can't find any 'neg's and it can't return them. So I want to set defaults to let the system know, that there are only two types: 'pos' and 'neg'.

Are there any solutions for such cases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:

1. Get distinct Ids: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/
2. Do your search with your query param.
3. Filter distinct Ids which is not your query param. Append default values to result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!
I solved this problem by adding a simple if...else condition.